# I am developing a food applcation for hungry and needy people please suggest me name for application

Tags: forms, interface, names

Please suggest me names that shows  application is for hungry people food.

Comment: How about « Bread and Fish »

Answer (score 1):

Some names I came up with

1. Tight Belly
2. Affordafood
3. Budget Food Brigade
4. Pocket Savoury
5. Bargain Food
6. Tuppeny Food

I would suggest that you come up with a name yourself as you better know the app's functionalities.

**Further reading:**

[How to name your app](https://www.creativebloq.com/apps/tips-naming-app-9112818)